# Highlight text using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a context sensitive menu that needs text to be hightlighted in order for it to work. However, I'm having problems with selecting the text using Selenium. I start by finding the WebElement I'm looking for, before trying to interact with it using the different mouse events available.

When I'm trying to select parts of the text, it doesn't appear to do anything other than placing the marker at the end of the string.
This is what my textbox looks like:
[image: Trying to select parts of the text in code]

This is what I need it to look like, or in other words, what I need Selenium to select (Just did it manually for the purpose of illustration:

[image: Selected text manually]

This is along the lines of what I'm trying to do in code:

```
public static async Task HighlightElementByCssSelector(this RemoteWebDriver @this, string cssSelector, TimeSpan? timeout = null, TimeSpan? interval = null)
{
    var element = await @this.FindElementByCssSelectorAsync(".testmarker-registryentryedit .testmarker-title-field");
    Actions action = new Actions(@this).MoveToElement(element).ClickAndHold(element).MoveByOffset(10,0).Release();
    action.Build().Perform();
}
```

`@this` represents the Driver in this case, and the `FindElementByCssSelectorAsync` being part of a 'wrapper-framework'.
I've tried different combinations of MoveToElement, DragAndDrop, ClickAndHold etc, but I just can't get it to work. Any pointers as to what might be wrong here?

Comment: Do you need you use mouse? If not, you could try to use the chord method from [Keys](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git-history/master/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#chord-java.lang.Iterable-). Or from Actions send keyDown with Shift key and then sendKeys() with left arrow and then keyUp() again?

Comment: That's a valid way to go. No need to use the mouse explictly. Still can't place the marker at the beginning of the string though :(

Comment: Do you know whats the text in that input? If so you can calculate the begging using string length and indexof your desired value and move the cursor to the correct position using the method in previous comment (without shift)

Comment: Or you mean to the beginning of that input box? That would be CTRL+LEFT I guess.

Comment: I mean start highlighting from the beginning towards the end :) Still not getting it to work though.

Comment: Could you update the code in the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to what I understood about your problem I tried to solve it on my local machine (first day of vacation, lol). Sorry, I don't have VS on that machine so I wrote it in Java. The code should be self-explanatory:

```
@org.junit.Test
public void doTest(){
    String query = "This is a test";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    WebElement searchBox = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lst-ib")));
    searchBox.sendKeys(query);

    // make sure it has focus
    searchBox.click();

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    // go to the beginning of input
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.HOME).build().perform();
    int length = query.substring(0, query.indexOf("a")).length();

    actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);
    }
    actions.keyUp(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT);
    actions.build().perform();
}
```

Results in:

[image: Result]

Is this what you wanted?