# How to mark text background in blue, similar to dragging the mouse over the text) with selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, css, selenium, webdriver

I have an HTML element as seen below:

```
<td title="11607" style="text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;">11607</td>
```

The locator I use to find the element is:

```
string number= "11607";
IWebElement element = DriverUser.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//*[contains(text(),'{0}')]" , number)));
```

I want to mark the text 11607 using selenium web driver,

After searching for a long while I found 2 solutions to the issue;
The first solution seemed to be the best fit but did not work for me. I want to know if it's because the HTML tag is TD or because it was not the right solution.
The other solution worked, but I would like to improve it.

I will detail below:

1. The first solution is: 
   (taken from [Highlight text using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517561/highlight-text-using-selenium))

```
public static void HighlightText(this IWebElement element)
        {
            element.Click();
            Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
            actions.SendKeys(Keys.Home).Build().Perform();
            int length = element.Text.Length;
            actions.KeyDown(Keys.LeftShift);
            for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
            {
                actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowRight);
            }
            actions.KeyUp(Keys.LeftShift);
            actions.Build().Perform();
        }
```

When I ran it, it did nothing.

**Maybe it's because my tag is a TD tag and not an INPUT or something like that?**

2. The second solution is: 
   (taken from https://www.edgewordstraining.co.uk/2018/02/23/highlighting-web-elements/, and appeared in other places)

```
        public static void HighlightTextJS(this IWebElement element)
        {
            var jsDriver = ( IJavaScriptExecutor ) Driver;
            string highlightJavascript = @"$(arguments[0]).css({ ""background"" : ""DodgerBlue""});";
            jsDriver.ExecuteScript(highlightJavascript , new object[] { element });
        }
```

It marks all the background of the element and not just the letters. I want to simulate dragging a mouse cursor over text accurately.

According to the attached screenshot
I get a view like the first line (11604)
but interested in a view like the second row (11602)

[image: mark text as blue]

**Maybe there is a property I can add to the CSS to simulate it?**




**Additionally** I tried option of send some keys by SendKeys:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
                actions.MoveToElement(element);
                actions.SendKeys(Keys.Shift + Keys.ArrowLeft + Keys.ArrowLeft + Keys.ArrowLeft + Keys.ArrowLeft);
                actions.Build().Perform();
```

and this too:

```
 Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
                actions.SendKeys(element, Keys.Shift + Keys.ArrowLeft + Keys.ArrowLeft + Keys.ArrowLeft + Keys.ArrowLeft);
                actions.Build().Perform();
```

It still didn't work.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, the first solution is for Input element, so did not work for you. If you can convert this python code to C#, it should work: `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 1, 1).click_and_hold().move_to_element_with_offset(elem, elem.size['width'], 1).release().perform()`

Comment: I convert your suggested code  to C#:            `new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(element).ClickAndHold().MoveByOffset(element.Size.Width , 1).Release().Perform();`
and it works! But it also marks two neighboring values that precede it in the same table row. I will be happy to solve this as well, but at the same time, what is there is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the C# syntax of the solution for you.

```
new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(element, 1, 1).ClickAndHold().MoveToElement(element, element.Size.Width-1, 1).Release().Perform();
```

In your attempt, it is starting from center of the element and going until width of element calculated from center of element. But this should start from top left of element and go till width of element.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Kamal, I run your exactly code, and now it mark my text + one "neighbor", why is it happening?

Comment: I am not sure if it will work but just try this once: `new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(element, 1, 1).ClickAndHold().MoveToElement(element, element.Size.Width-1, 1).Release().Perform();`

Comment: btw, why did you used with Release() and not with Build()?

Comment: @C.Mar, please accept the answer, if your problem is solved. And, I am not familiar with `Build()` method available in C#, no such method in python. So `Release()` is just releasing the mouse button held with `ClickAndHold()`.

Comment: I accepted your answer. and thanks for the explanations. Have a nice day.